# In an e-commerce website, what is the exact point which we need to deduct the quantity bought from the product?

Tags: e-commerce

If we do it right before the person add payment details, if the payment failed, we have to pay extra attention to the qty

We can also do it after he add the payment info and after the IPG verify them. But before we confirm the order (The user will be charged only if we confirm).

The second method seems to be better but is it good for the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after the customer has entered billing/credit info and you have validated as much as you can - present them with the final total to complete the transaction. when you do that also check the quantity and price of the items they are ordering to confirm both.

IF the transaction completes, which for a real order will be a few seconds later because customer has entered credit card - then deduct the inventory. Obvious exceptions to this would be auctions, tickets, etc - then you have to hold the inventory through the check out process, AND you are clearly informing the customer that the store is only holding the inventory for X minutes.

would be curious how amazon handles this. its probably different depending on which product category.